# How do I link my site running on Google App Engine to use Google+ login?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus

I am trying to run a site on Google App Engine (in python).  I have it working with the default users.create_login_url(...) but I am wondering if I can override that method to work with a Google+ login?  Or if there is another method to be able to user the Google+ authentication services with Google App Engine.  I'm pretty new to both, but everything I've read has been very unclear on how to merge the two.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe you just want to enable the Federated Login. Try going to Application Settings > Authentication Type > Federated Login

Comment: @Lipis what do you mean by Federated Login? I'm designing my own application to run on an Google App Engine.  I would just like to somehow integrate the user that the Google+ login retrieves and send it to the google app engine so when I call users.create_login_url(...) I get that user back.  Currently I am getting back "None".  Thanks!